# Is there a way to get a list of all IP addresses and host names that I can connect to on a local network via python

Tags: python, configuration, network-programming, ip, local-network

Is there a way, preferably in python but command line or possibly powershell is doable for me as well, to find every possible hostname that my username and password can connect to, then temporarily connect and request system settings (OS type for example.)

Of course I want to restrict this to my local network, not attempt to connect to like google or facebook, just because I can also ping them.

The local network is very large, and may be multiple base IP addresses, not just some 192.168.1.x stuff.  Between 60,000 and 100,000 devices should be connected at any given time

For clarity, I am trying to see what is within my network, based on either proxy settings or another method, then extract a small amount of data from those locations under the assumption that all of them are configured such that a user I have access to has super permission to all devices.

My apologies if the wording is unclear. Im a python dev but I am not familiar with networking almost at all. My organization just went through a restructure, and now I am being given a request to do something I've never been involved with, and network related employees are currently unavailable as they continue to try to mitigate and help fix problems with 20,000+ additional work from home.

Comment: This problem requires network commands in your OS's command language; it was straightforward to look up by removing the "Python" requirement.  Simply extract the system commands from the cited duplicate and execute them with `os.system()`.

Comment: This is different, as Im not just pinging the end digits like a local router.  I am looking within a network containing over 80,000 concurrent machines.  The base IP could be different.  Is it possible for you to reopen this?

Comment: Got it; thanks for the correction.  You're right.  I reopened the question.  I looked for duplicates -- wider-based questions to address your expanded issue -- and didn't find anything usable at your scale.  Thanks to your edit, I could reverse my down-vote on the question, too.